# NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize XXX class after deploying on spark standalone cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, deployment, spark-streaming, spark-submit

I wrote a spark streaming application built with sbt. It works perfectly fine locally, but after deploying on the cluster, it complains about a class I wrote which clearly in the fat jar (checked using jar tvf). The following is my project structure. XXX object is the one that spark complains about

```
src
`-- main
    `-- scala
        |-- packageName
        |   `-- XXX object
        `-- mainMethodEntryObject
```

My submit command:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
  --class mainMethodEntryObject \
  --master REST_URL\
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  hdfs:///FAT_JAR_PRODUCED_BY_SBT_ASSEMBLY
```

Specific error message:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class XXX
```

Comment: can you add the command used to launch job and when you run `jar tvf `what response it returns?

Comment: @techsquids sure, see above

Comment: `jar tvf` does it list the packagename at root of the jar?

Comment: @techsquids yes, I run `jar tvf target/scala-2.11/FAT_JAR_NAME` at root of my project, and it has `packageName/XXX.class` in it

Comment: strange, normally all of your jar classes should be available at runtime. try adding main jar in --lib also in `spark-submit` command.

Comment: can it be a java installed version problem? check if all the machines are running with the same java version. I had similar problems previously due to that

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue for a reason similar to this user: 
http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-is-this-a-bug-td18972.html

I was calling a method on an object that had a few variables defined on the object itself, including spark and a logger, like this

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .getOrCreate()

val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass.getName)
```

The function I was calling called another function on the object, which called another function, which called yet another function on the object inside of a `flatMap` call on an rdd.

I was getting the `NoClassDefFoundError` error in a stacktrace where the previous 2 function calls in the stack trace were functions on the class Spark was telling me did not exist.

Based on the conversation linked above, my hypothesis was that the global `spark` reference wasn't getting initialized by the time the function that used it was getting called (the one that resulted in the `NoClassDefFoundError` exception).

After quite a few experiments, I found that this pattern worked to resolve the problem.

```
// Move global definitions here
object MyClassGlobalDef {

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .getOrCreate()

  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass.getName)

}

// Force the globals object to be initialized
import MyClassGlobalDef._

object MyClass {
  // Functions here
}
```

It's kind of ugly, but Spark seems to like it.

Comment: i had a similar issue and this solved it. but it's still puzzling to me. my code used to run fine until a couple of days ago. do you know what's root cause for this?

Comment: I suspect the problem has something to do with how Spark does serialization, but aside from that I'm not sure. I haven't dug into this deep enough to debug.

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to say without the code but it looks like a problem of serialization of your XXX object. I can't say I understand perfectly why, but the point is that the object is not shipped to the executor.

The solution that worked for me is to convert your object to a class that extends `Serializable` and just instantiate it where you need it. So basically, if I'm not wrong you have

```
object test {
   def foo = ...
}
```

which would be used as `test.foo` in your main, but you need at minimum

```
class Test extends Serializable {
   def foo = ...
}
```

and then in your main have `val test = new Test` at the beginning and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

It is related to serialization. I fixed this by adding "implements Serializable" and serialVersionUID field to given class.

Comment: This was the fix for me!